# take the value from onitemselect in autocompletetextview

Tags: android

amount is not being set to EditText, only stores in another external variable.

```
productAtoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        amount.setText(map.get((String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way:

```
amount.setText(map.get(position));
```

or this way:

```
amount.setText((String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
```